# Share Password Protected folder and Non-Password Protected Folder Together in a Computer

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have a computer ( Windows 7) which is password protected. There is a folder which I want to share with everyone in my current company network.

Is there anyway to share that folder without letting my colleagues know the computer password?

**I realize that there is something that is missing in my original question; in reality, I want password protection for certain folders, and no password protection for other public folders.**

**P/S: The computer is setup in a workgroup**

Comment: Is the computer set up on a domain or in a workgroup?

Comment: The computer is setup in a workgroup

Answer (score 2):

1. Launch your **Control Panel**.
2. Click on **Network and Sharing Center**. A new window will pop-up.
3. Click on **Change Advanced Sharing Center** from sidebar at left side of that window.
4. Click on Option (radio button) **Turn off password protected Sharing**.
5. Now click on **Save Settings**.

Now, there is no need to enter password in remote computer to access your files and folders.

Comment: I realize that there is something that is missing in my original question; in reality, I want password protection for certain folders, and no password protection for other public folders.

Comment: Doesn't work in my case. Is there anything else I might need to enable or disable?

Answer (score 0):

If you share a folder with "Everyone" it should not require any credentials to access (results may vary depending on which Windows 7 version you're using).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway to share that folder without letting my colleagues know the computer password?

Yes, you need to create another user with non-administrative privileges and share that username and password with your colleagues instead of your own user.

> I want password protection for certain folders, and no password protection for other public folders.

For public folder set the access permission on the share to everyone. To enable password protection on some folders, remove the everyone group from the permissions and add the newly created non-administrative user.